# How to Run a Macro without using Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Iam a DB Guy and i dont know anything about VB.
I have a Macro in Excel and in Excel i have cross tabular records.
My macro will convert Crosstabular records to tabular records.
But My requirement is i want to Run the Same Macro outside the excel.
.VBS file should be there and whenever we run the .VBS it should pick excel from some place and convert the crosstab records to tabular records and save at some different location.
I have created a Code for the same by googling and Somebody Please review my below code and help me with the Proper code.

```
Sub RunMacro()

Dim xlApp 'As Excel.Application 

Dim xlBook 'As Workbook 

Dim xlSheet 'As Worksheet

Dim wsCrossTab 'As Worksheet

Dim wsList 'As Worksheet

Dim iLastCol 'As Long

Dim iLastRow 'As Long

Dim iLastRowList 'As Long

Dim rngCTab 'As Range 'Used for range in Sheet1 cross tab sheet

Dim rngList 'As Range 'Destination range for the list

Dim I 'As Long


Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\Source.xls")

CrossTabToList()

xlBook.SaveAs "D:\Results.xls"

xlApp.Quit

End Sub

Sub CrossTabToList()

Set wsCrossTab = Worksheets("Tabular")

Set wsList = Worksheets.Add


'Find the last row in Sheet1 with the cross tab

iLastRow = wsCrossTab.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Set the initial value for the row in the destination worksheet

iLastRowList = 2

'Find the last column in Sheet1 with the cross tab

iLastCol = wsCrossTab.Range("A8").End(xlToRight).Column

'Create a new sheet and set the heading titles

wsList.Range("A1:C1") = Array("CATEGORY", "SUBCATEGORY", "VALUE")

'Start looping through the cross tab data

For I = 2 To iLastRow

Set rngCTab = wsCrossTab.Range("A" & I) 'initial value A2

Set rngList = wsList.Range("A" & iLastRowList) 'initial value A2

'Copy individual names in Col A (A2 initially) into as many rows as there are data columns in the cross tab (less 1 for Col A).

rngCTab.Copy rngList.Resize(iLastCol - 1)

'Move up a I rows less one and across one column (using offset function) to select heading row. Copy.

rngCTab.Offset(-(I - 1), 1).Resize(, iLastCol - 1).Copy

'Paste transpose to columns in the list sheet alongside the names

rngList.Offset(0,1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

'Staying on same row (2 initially) copy the data from the cross tab

rngCTab.Offset(, 1).Resize(, iLastCol - 1).Copy

'Past transpose as column in list sheet

rngList.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

'Set the new last row in list sheet to be just below the last name copied

iLastRowList = iLastRowList + (iLastCol - 1)

'increment I by 1

 Next I


Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets("Tabular").Select

ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Results"

objwkbk.SaveAs "D:\Results.xls"


End Sub
```

---

Thanks,

Praveen

---

As i mentioned i am not a Java Developer or Coding guy,i am a Database person ,i dont know anything about Java .I want to use the above code as .VBS file.I want somebody to correct my above code to use it in a .VBS File.If you can do that it will be really appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: When you try to run this code what happens?  What error messages (if any) do you get.  How does Excel behave when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

That's a very good idea.  VBA in an Excel file can confuse users, so I try to avoid that whenever possible.

I recommend storing your procedure in an Access file. There's a little work involved in converting it, but this should get you started:

1. Make a new Access db
2. In your new db, make a new VBA **module**.  Paste your code in there.
3. Add your most  current version of **Microsoft Excel Object Library**.
4. Make whatever other changes are necessary to get the code in working order again (you'll have to do a bit of trial and error. Run the code repeatedly and deal with the error messages as they pop up)
5. Change your **Sub** to a **Function** (you need to do this to call it from a Macro)
6. Make a new **Macro**.  Add the action **RunCode** with the argument **RunMacro()**

In the future, all you will have to do is open the db and click on the macro to run the code.

Comment: As i mentioned i am not a Java Developer or Coding guy,i am a Database person ,i dont know anything about Java .I want to use the above code as .VBS file.I want somebody to correct my above code to use it in a .VBS File.If you can do that it will be really appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Ah, in that case I can't be of much help. Good luck.